# Should I clean the belly button of a newborn after the "stump" falls off

Tags: newborn

My newborn's umbilical cord stump just fell off, we are wondering if it is necessary or even good to clean the newly exposed belly button with alcohol or hydrogen peroxide or anything else. The Doctor didn't really give much instruction other than "keep the stump dry".